# How to use the current class template as template parameter for another template?

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, metaprogramming

I'm using recursive templates classes that inherit recursively.
I'm trying to define an abstract way of getting the n-th base (like base 0 is the current class, base 1 is its base, base 2 is the base's base etc.).

(In this example the template parameters are `size_t` but the same principle applies with `typename` or `class`.)

I can do this fine using a helper struct, partially specialized. But I want to make it independent of the template (and not make a helper struct whenever I have a recursive template), as follows:

```
namespace helper
{
    template<template<size_t...> typename templ, size_t pos, size_t s0, size_t... rest>
    struct getter
    {
        typedef typename getter<templ, pos - 1, rest...>::type type;
        type &operator()(templ<s0, rest...> &s)
        {
            getter<templ, pos - 1, rest...> getter;
            return getter(static_cast<templ<rest...>&> (s));
        }
    };
    template<template<size_t...> typename templ, size_t s0, size_t... rest>
    struct getter<templ, 0, s0, rest...>
    {
        typedef templ<s0, rest...> type;
        type &operator()(templ<s0, rest...> &s)
        {
            return s;
        }
    };
}
```

Now, in my template class, I want to use this helper to make a function `get<size_t n>()` that returns me a reference to the n-th base (code fails to compile at `get` declaration):

```
template<size_t...>
struct record {};

template<size_t n, size_t... rest>
struct record<n, rest...> : record<rest...>, value<n>
{
    template<size_t pos>
    typename helper::getter<record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type &get()
    {
        helper::getter<record, pos, n, rest...> getter;
        return static_cast<typename helper::getter<record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type&>(getter(*this));
    }
};
```

This fails because, inside the `record` template, `record` is the final class and not the template. I would like to use something like "current template" instead of "currently instantiated class".

The only workaround I've found (which works under Visual Studio 2015) is to use a global alias to replicate the template:

```
template<size_t...s>
using g_record = record<s...>;
```

and then modify the get declaration to call the global alias (which points to the same type):

```
...
template<size_t pos>
typename helper::getter<g_record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type &get()
{
    helper::getter<g_record, pos, n, rest...> getter;
    return static_cast<typename helper::getter<g_record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type&>(getter(*this));
}
...
```

Is there a more direct or a "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be necessary to use any tricks to get the compiler to realize you are using `record` as a template name instead of a type name referring to the current instantiation. See [temp.local]/1, emphasis mine:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name* can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a *template-argument-list*,
>   **as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter***, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, **it refers to the class template itself**. Otherwise, it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.

The workaround you posted is correct, but it should not be needed; this is a bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I was a bit hasty in my digging.

Apparently using the template's fully qualified name works (in my example it's `::record`):

```
    template<size_t pos>
    typename helper::getter<::record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type &get()
    {
        helper::getter<::record, pos, n, rest...> getter;
        return static_cast<typename helper::getter<::record, pos, n, rest...>::type::value_type&>(getter(*this));
    }
```